# Puppeteer get <img> src attribute in a lazy loading page

Tags: image, web-scraping, puppeteer, lazy-loading

When I scrape [a page](https://www.fnac.es/Moviles-en-oferta/n94157) using puppeteer and I try to read "img" element "src" attribute to download later the images.

```
  const imgs = await page.$$eval("img.Article-itemVisualImg[src]", (imgs) =>
    imgs.map((img) => img.getAttribute("src"))
  );
```

I get the data like this. I suspect it is due to lazy loading since all the images except the first one have the "data-lazyimage" attribute in "img" element.

```
 'https://static.fnac-static.com/multimedia/Images/ES/NR/37/bd/6b/7060791/1545-1.jpg',
  'https://static.fnac-static.com/multimedia/Images/ES/NR/7a/d4/61/6411386/1545-1.jpg',
  "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'/%3E",
  "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'/%3E",
  "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'/%3E",
  "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'/%3E",
.....
```

How could I get the full URL of the JPG file for all the images, including for those which I get a string that start with "data:image/svg+xml". I do not understand what is happening since all the "img" elements have a "src" attribute with the URL of the JPG file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct: all the images except for the first one are lazy-loaded. `data:image/svg+xml` images in the src attribute are simply minimal placeholders.

We can conclude that all images but the first one must contain `data-lazyimage` attribute; the first one will have `src`. With that in mind let's query for lazy attribute first and if it doesn't exist, fall back to src:

```
const imgs = await page.$$eval("img.Article-itemVisualImg[src]", (imgs) =>
  imgs.map((img) => img.getAttribute("data-lazyimage") || img.getAttribute("src"))
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
imgs.map((img) => img.getAttribute("data-lazyimage") || img.getAttribute("src"))
```

That will get the lazy src if it's there and src if it isn't